# Django - meta class

Tags: django, metaclass

When amending a meta class to include a unique_together and trying to makemigrations, I keep getting "No changes detected" which I'm presuming isn't expected behaviour. ***ERROR #1***

I did try and remove the migration for that particular model and makemigration but that still doesn't include this meta class attribute.

I can in fact force a migration by changing other aspects of the model and then manually editing the migration.py which works. However when using the model in a tabularinline and overriding the save_formset I get the "Enum value with this Enum code already exists".***ERROR #2***

[Dirty message: Unique constraint screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qnlbv.png)

**Model.py**

```
class EnumValue(models.Model):
    enum_code = models.CharField(max_length=16, unique=True)
    enum_value_en = models.CharField(max_length=40, verbose_name='English VALUE')
    lowercase_enum_value_en = models.CharField(max_length=500, db_index=True)
    enum = models.ForeignKey(Enum, db_index=True, verbose_name='Enum')
    created_date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    modified_date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
    created_by = models.ForeignKey(User, related_name='enumvalue_created_by_user')
    modified_by = models.ForeignKey(User, related_name='enumvalue_updated_by_user')

class Meta:
    unique_together = (('enum_code', 'enum'),)
    ordering = ('lowercase_enum_value_en',)

def __unicode__(self):
    return self.enum_value_en

class Meta:
    verbose_name_plural = 'Enum Values'
```

**Migration.py**

```
class Migration(migrations.Migration):

dependencies = [
    ('dq', '0031_enum_enumvalue'),
]

operations = [
    migrations.AlterUniqueTogether(
        name='enumvalue',
        unique_together=set([('enum_code', 'enum')]),
    ),
]
```

**Admin - tabularinline **

```
def save_formset(self, request, form, formset, change):
    if formset.is_valid: # ensures no blank forms are submitted
        instances = formset.save(commit=False) # gets instance from memory and add to it before saving it
        for obj in formset.deleted_objects:
            obj.delete()
        for instance in instances:
            instance.modified_by = request.user
            instance.created_by = request.user
            instance.lowercase_enum_value_en = instance.enum_value_en.lower() # no need to get clean data from "form"
            instance.save()
        formset.save()
```

**I'm using Django v1.8.4**

Comment: This can be caused by many things, your post is too broad. First of all, check what migrations was made with `manage.py showmigratons`. If you made migration in the past with the same name as your current migration, database will think it was already made.

Comment: showmigrations doesn't suggest a duplicate name. When I makemigrations I would expect the metaclass change to be detected as a change and it doesn't which is my underlying problem. In essence I'm asking should a change to the meta class trigger a new migration (error #1) and because I've manually hacked the migration this in turn causes the other error I've marked as #2. Many thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `EnumValue` class has *two* `Meta` classes. This behaves just like reassigning a variable: the first class definition is lost, and only the second class definition remains. You need to merge these together into a single class.

```
class EnumValue(models.Model):
    ...
    class Meta:
        unique_together = (('enum_code', 'enum'),)
        ordering = ('lowercase_enum_value_en',)
        verbose_name_plural = 'Enum Values'

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.enum_value_en
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the cause is that your `enum_code` field already has `unique=True` by itself. Thus it's automatically unique together with any other field without needing a migration, and your error is also explained.

Comment: thanks remo, my bad, that was an oversight and errors when it should. However I'm not getting the clean error message. For example "Enum with this Enum Value and Enum Id already exists". Instead I get the  "IntegrityError at /admin/dq/enumvalue/add/ ORA-00001: unique constraint (SAP_DS_01.D1301C0ACA6DBFD7B9592F0E5C3391) violated...."

Comment: Did you create a migration when you removed the unique from the field, and apply it? Seems the database still thinks the field is unique.

Comment: No, but the unique constraint is now across both columns which I'm able to violate but the issue is that the error message should be clean, i.e. "Enum with this Enum Value and Enum Id already exists". Please see screenshot attached to my original post